Creating/Extracting/Separating Component Library From Main App
I use expo with development builds (expo-dev-client) in an app i'm working on.
There are external libraries that use native code and this is not an issue as I use the dev builds.
Now, I want to separate and extract all my custom components in the app into a library of its own so I can use them in another companion app. Bear in mind, these components employ some of the external libraries referenced earlier.
Is this possible, separating the components into an external library?
If yes, that would mean I'd be using expo-dev-client in my custom-component-library.
I need help getting started with this, I have tried different starters out there but none of them seem to reference expo-dev-client.
I have even created new projects and they work but falls apart when I add expo-dev-client
What concepts and way of thinking do I need to adopt or ditch?
